# ImageMagick different behavior on local and on server

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a different result on my local machine and on the server when I overlay image. On local, I have Ubuntu, apache2, php7.1. On the server, I have Debian 8, apache2, php7.1.

And I have similar libraries on local and on server.

```
        $image = new Imagick(saveImage($imagelink, $imageName));

        $overlayImage = new Imagick(data('images', 'casa_bottom'));

        $overlayImage->setImageBackgroundColor("transparent");
        $overlayImage->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);

        $image->compositeImage($overlayImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 17, ($image->getImageHeight()-$overlayImage->getImageHeight())-15, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
        $image->writeImage( "./images/$imageName");
```

Result on local have watermark with transparent background but on server it is not transparent.

-----EDIT-----

same date 2017-05-26

Image from local[image]

Image from server[image]

Comment: Check compiled versions of Imagick (extension versions) ...

Comment: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-05-26  - same on local and on server, also same module versions

Comment: What library are you using to interface with ImageMagick?

Comment: Imagick http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: Do the delegates you have installed have the same version numbers on your two platforms? Do the version numbers of ImageMagick have the same dates associated with them. Perhaps one has been patched with a more recent date. Can you post your input and output images so we can see how they differ?

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: Something you assume but do not prove is that you have the same watermark source images on both machines. So what are the MD5 hashes for these images?